# How should the specification pattern handle null candidates?

Tags: language-agnostic, null-check, specification-pattern

I am just wondering if there is a recommended strategy for dealing with `null` candidates in the specification pattern. As I see it, there are two possible strategies:

- Throw an exception if the candidate is `null`.
- Return `false` for cases where `null` is not a valid candidate value.

*Examples are written in Kotlin, but this could easily apply to C# and Java as well.*

**Example - Throw an exception**

```
class RangeSpecification<T : Comparable<T>>(
    private val min: T,
    private val max: T
) : Specification<T?>() {

    override fun isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T?): Boolean {
        checkNotNull(candidate) 
        // ^ Throws IllegalStateException("Required value was null.")
        return candidate in min..max
    }
}
```

**Example - Return false**

```
class RangeSpecification<T : Comparable<T>>(
    private val min: T,
    private val max: T
) : Specification<T?>() {

    override fun isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T?): Boolean {
        return candidate != null && candidate in min..max
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether this qualifies as an opinionated question (and apologies if that's the case), but I'm just wondering which approach is more suitable in line with the specification pattern?

**References**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern
- https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/02/08/specification-pattern-c-implementation/
- https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf

Comment: I think it depends entirely on the domain and whether `null` is a valid value for `candidate` or represents an error condition.

Comment: @jaco0646 This was the conclusion I eventually came to